# How to open A HTML page with windows-1252 encoding in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I try to parse a HTML document with beautifulsoup but I run in troubles. What is the best way to open a HTML document with windows-1252 encoding?

I tried with iconv to convert to utf-8 but this also doesn't work.

```
doc = open("e.html").read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)

soup.findAll('p')
```

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 103: ordinal not in range(128)

When I open it without iconv I get the same error.

full traceback:

```
>>> soup.findAll('p')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 103: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: I wonder what that `fromEncoding` argument could be for...

Comment: makes no difference `soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, fromEncoding="windows-1252")` the same result with `soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, fromEncoding="utf-8")`

Comment: What does the full traceback say then?

Comment: added the traceback in my post

Comment: *That* problem has lots and lots of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position
>   723617: invalid continuation byte

What worked for me was to specify the input encoding like so:

```
page = open("page.html", encoding="windows-1252")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
doc = open("e.html").read()

doc = doc.decode('cp1252')

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)

soup.findAll('p')
```

Comment: @berndmeiers82 Hmmm... Try to change `soup.findAll('p')` to something like `result = soup.findAll('p')` My assumption that you get this error since `soup.findAll('p')` produce an output to the console which couldn't be encoded with 'ascii' codec